# Template for changing text on membership confirmation

Tags: drupal, civimember, custom-templates

There's this text that shows on the membership confirmation page that says: "Select a Membership Level"

It looks odd since you're not selecting anything on this page, it's just the confirmation. It should say something like "Chosen Membership Level". However, I can't seem to find which template is creating that text so I can change it out.

[image]

Comment: i don't recall seeing that. not seeing it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2

Comment: It shows up on the review page on all my sites, even those without custom templates. So it's got to be coming from Civi somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use Word Replacement from the Adminstration menu (unless exactly the same text appears elsewhere in the sign up process).

Comment: Yea, if I can't figure out the template, that was my next option. I just don't know if it shows up elsewhere. It seems like every time I do that, later I find out that it's also in some obscure spot that now looks funny.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that word replacements is an option but to find it just do

`grep -r "Select a Membership Level" templates`

It shows up twice in templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/MembershipBlock.tpl

Note that sometimes it is a radio since the block is used elsewhere.

Comment: I'll look again, as I didn't see it in that template when I had looked earlier. I don't currently have any sort of command line access on their site, which makes it harder to find things. I just have to manually search through the templates.

Comment: Assuming its in the core code (and it is in this case) you could just save the distrubution anywhere and search it.

As its there twice, then it may be needed as is in one of the cases so editing the template may be the best route. Haven't looked in any detail.